# Harmonic oscillator propagator in Euclidean time

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, greens-functions, propagator, wick-rotation, thermal-field-theory

I'm following Nastase's book on Quantum Field Theory but this question is just about quantum mechanics in the path integral formalism. In chapter 8 he considers the propagator equation for a harmonic oscillator
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+\omega^2\right)\Delta(t-t')=\delta(t-t'),$$
which under Wick rotation $t\to -i\tau$ turns into
$$\left(-\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+\omega^2\right)\Delta_{E}(\tau-\tau')=\delta(\tau-\tau'),$$
where the subscript $E$ stands for Euclidean.

Now, I'm having troubles with checking that the unique periodic solution $$\Delta_{E}(\tau-\tau'\pm\beta)=\Delta_{E}(\tau-\tau')$$ for the propagator equation in Euclidean time turns to be
$$\Delta_E(\tau-\tau')=\frac{1}{2\omega}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{\beta|\omega|}-1}\right)e^{-\omega(\tau-\tau')}+\frac{1}{e^{\beta|\omega|}-1}e^{\omega(\tau-\tau')}\right].$$

When I treat this as an ansatz and plug it back in the propagator equation I don't get the $\delta(\tau-\tau')$ so I would appreciate any insight on this computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I'd  do the Bosonic problem for the case $\beta=2\pi$, $\omega=M$. (I am cut and pasting  from old notes which is why I have chosen these parameters)

Star with
$$
\Delta(\tau-\tau')= \frac 1 {2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{in(\tau-\tau')}}{n^2+M^2}
$$
which gives the delta via
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{in\tau}= \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty 2\pi \delta(\tau+2\pi m).$$

Now evaluate the sum as follows:
$$
 \frac 1{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{in\tau}}{n^2+M^2}=
   \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty   \frac 1{2|M |} e^{-|M||\tau+2\pi n|}, \quad \hbox{(Poisson Summation)}\nonumber\\
   =  \frac 1 {2M} \frac{\cosh(\pi -\tau)M}{\sinh \pi M}, \quad0 <\tau<2\pi,\nonumber\\
   = \frac 1{2M} e^{-M\tau} +\frac 1 M\frac{ \cosh M\tau}{(e^{2\pi M}-1)}\quad0 <\tau<2\pi.\nonumber
  % = \frac 1{2M} (\coth \pi M\cosh M \tau- \sinh M\tau) \nonumber
 $$
The first line come from applying Poisson summation to the zero temperature expression
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{ik\tau}} {k^2+M^2}=\frac 1 {2|M|}e^{-|\tau||M|} 
$$
and has the  physical interpretation as  the method-of-images sum over the  $n$-fold winding of the particle trajectory around the periodic imaginary time direction.
The passage from the first  to second  lines is just summing  the two  geometric series from  $n=0$ to $ \infty$ and $n=-\infty$ to $-1$.

In this "$\cosh(\pi -\tau)$" version  the delta function comes from the restriction on $\tau$ which leads to discontinuity in the slope of $\Delta(\tau-\tau')$  at $\tau-\tau'=2\pi m$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How we would recover the delta function from the third line where you get the propagator? When I input that into the propagator equation I always get 0.

Comment: Also, any idea on how to perform the integral analytically?

Comment: Graph the function $\cosh(\pi -\tau)$ for $0<\tau<2\pi$, and take into account $\tau \to \tau+2\pi$ the periodicity. Observe that there  are cusps at $\tau=2\pi n$. Their second derivative  gives the delta functions. Ignoring the periodicity and just plugging in the formula away from $2\pi n$ will miss the deltas.  What do youmean by evaluate analytically? We have the exact answer already!

Comment: Thank you, yes, I had troubles because when applying the operator $(-d^2/d\tau^2+\omega^2)$ I didn't get the delta. About the integral, I know you got the exact answer but I wanted to ask you how you did it?

Comment: Which integral?  Do you mean the Fourier transform of $(k^2+M^2)^{-1}$? That is easy. Just do the inverse FT of the RHS. Alternativly construct the non-period Green function of $-\nabla^2+M^2$, or even do it by a contour integral.